# Extjs Combo Box Not Updating

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I've got a combo box in ExtJS 4.2 that I initially create with a store that has 0 items. Later on I compute a bunch of things and update the combo box use loadRawData on the store associated with the combobox. Somehow, the store gets updated, I've stepped through the code to make sure, but the combobox doesn't see any updates.

Here's the code that creates the extjs stuff and a link to the relevant jsfiddle:

```
Ext.define('ItemTemplateModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
        { name: 'id', type: 'int' },
        { name: 'imageUri', type: 'string' },
        { name: 'name', type: 'string' }
    ]
});

var itemTemplateStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    model: 'ItemTemplateModel',
    autoLoad: false,
    proxy: {
        type: 'memory',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'entries'
        }
    }
});

var comboBox = Ext.create('Ext.form.field.ComboBox', {
    store: itemTemplateStore,
    fieldLabel: 'Item Template',
    name: 'template',
    displayField: 'name',
    valueField: 'id',
    editable: false,
    typeAhead: false,
    triggerAction: 'all'
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qqHYp/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use memory proxy - need to add

```
queryMode: 'local',
```

in combo config:
http://jsfiddle.net/qqHYp/4/

Comment: Wow, I can't believe that that isn't a store property, and that combobox is the only item with that property. Seems like ExtJS really dropped the ball here.

Comment: Just ran across this too, I never would have thought that this was required when attempting a local store.loadRawData()